# Resizing and adjusting text and plots dynamically in ggplot when generating EnhancedVolcano plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the EnhancedVolcano package in R to generate plots, which utilizes ggplot2 under the hood. When I try to save the plots at various dimensions using ggsave(), I've noticed that the text and titles remain the same size, causing the main plot contents to shrink and become less visible in smaller figures.

Here's a minimal reproducible example to illustrate the issue:

```
# Sample data for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
toptable <- data.frame(
  gene = letters[1:10],
  log2FoldChange = runif(10, -2, 2),
  pvalue = runif(10, 0, 0.05)
)

plot <- EnhancedVolcano(toptable,
    lab = toptable$gene,
    x = 'log2FoldChange',
    y = 'pvalue',
    title = 'My Volcano Plot'
)

# Save with default dimensions
ggsave('default_plot.png', plot)

# Save with smaller dimensions
ggsave('small_plot.png', plot, width = 3, height = 2)
```

With the above, the text size remains constant between default_plot.png and small_plot.png, making the smaller plot's contents hard to see.

How can I programmatically adjust the text size and other theme elements in my EnhancedVolcano plots to ensure that they save well at various dimensions?

The same issue arises when I try to plot multiple plots using CowPlot. The plotting area will collapse while all other elements remain the same size. Is there a why to either shrink all elements or fix the plotting area?

I have tried to following fix and while this works for the above example it still requires a lot of trial and error to plot multiple plots.

Ideally there is a plot and the entire plot is a fixed aspect ratio that shrinks everything in size. Is this possible?

```
generate_theme <- function(base_size = 24) {
    theme_bw(base_size = base_size) +
    theme(
        legend.background = element_rect(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = base_size * 1.1, face = 'bold'),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = base_size * 0.9),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = base_size * 0.8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = base_size * 0.8),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = base_size * 0.8),
        axis.title = element_text(size = base_size)
    )
}
```